# i3status alsa mixer

Tags: ubuntu, audio, i3

How do I get i3status to display the volume level from `alsamixer` instead of `Pulseaudio`?

This is my volume configuration right now:

```
volume master {
        format = "♪: %volume"
        format_muted = "♪: muted (%volume)"
        device = "default"
        mixer = "Master"
}
```

According to the [docs](https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_volume), setting `device` to 'default', PulseAudio will be tried if detected and will fallback to ALSA (Linux) or OSS (FreeBSD/OpenBSD). **What string do I use for ALSA?**

I have tried `"alsa"` `"alsamixer"` `"ALSA"` and they don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
device = "sysdefault"
```

---

#### Explanation

Any value for `device` that is not `default` or does not start with `pulse` tells `i3status` not to use *PulseAudio* and fall back to *alsa*. The value is then directly passed to *alsa* as device indetifier, so just setting it to `alsa` or something similar will not work. Before `i3status` had support for *PulseAudio* you could just set it to `default` to have *alsa* use the default device. `default` is still a valid name for an *alsa* device. But `i3status` now tries to auto-detect *PulseAudio* and use it in preference to *alsa*, when device is set to `default` (or unset).

By using `sysdefault`, you can bypass the automatism in `i3status` while still using a valid general device name for *alsa*.

#### Trouble shooting

If using `systemdefault` does not work for some reason, you may have to use a specific device name. If you have only one sound card, `hw:0` should work.

```
device = "hw:0"
```

But on a modern desktop computer there may be more "sound cards" than one might expect. Aside from "true" on-board or dedicated sound cards there graphics cards (sound for HDMI), web cams, USB-Headsets, Bluetooth adapters, etc..

You can get a list of the cards in your system from the file `/proc/asound/cards`. For example:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xfa120000 irq 41
 1 [Nvidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Nvidia
                      HDA Nvidia at 0xd3000000 irq 16
```

These can then be accessed with the device names `hw:N` in `i3status.conf`, where `N` is the number in the first column.

If you need more information to decide, which device number is the correct one, you can use `amixer -c N info` (`amixer` can be found in the `alsa-utils` package):

```
% amixer -c 0 info
Card hw:0 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xfa120000 irq 41'
  Mixer name    : 'Realtek ALC262'
  Components    : 'HDA:10ec0262,103c1587,00100202'
  Controls      : 41
  Simple ctrls  : 20
```

With `amixer -c N` you get a complete list of all mixer controls and their settings for card `N`. With `amixer -c N sget CONTROL` you can retrieve a specific value. So you can use `amixer -c N sget Master`, to verify that the output from `i3status` matches the actual values in *alsa*.